# SSRS report parameter with customer properties

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, rdl

My SSRS report parameter information is following

[image]

Look carefully Each parameter has **custom** properties, have experience with report parameter in SSRS but it's new for me to handle custom properties with parameter
.Is it possible in SSRS use the parameter with customer properties.

Comment: You can't change the font size or colour in Report Builder.

Comment: @JonTout, thanks for your reply, is it possible to change the font.

Comment: the available Parameter options in Report Builder and Data Type and Source, so if it's a text parameter, date (show's calendar control), Integer etc and where the data source from the parameter is stored.

Nothing for font formatting.